Refracted Spherical Wavefront
Consider an optical wavefront propagating in a homogeneous medium with refractive index n.
Said wavefront encounters a spherical lens with radius of curvature R and refractive index n'.
At the boundary of the optical surface, the wavefront has a radius of curvature r (which describes whether the light is converging, diverging or collimated).
What would be the mathematical expression which yields the radius of curvature of the wavefront right after refraction at the boundary?

Read the article Surface power, with the object distance $o$ being the radius of curvature of the incoming wavefront at the boundary and the image distance $i$ being the radius of curvature of the outgoing wavefront at the boundary.

Thanks for the pointer. It is mentioned that the formula cited in the article is only valid under the paraxial approximation. Do you have a pointer for a precise formula?

I think that you need to go from an analytic solution to a numerical one.
